# angularjs chain http post sequentially

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

In my application, I am storing data in local storage and trigger async http post in the background. Once successfully posted, the posted data gets removed from local storage. When http post is in process, there may be more data added to local storage so I need to queue up the post and sequentially process it because, I need to wait for the local storage to be cleared from the successful posts. The task should be called recursively until there is data in local storage.

```
taskQueue: function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    queue.push(deferred);
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    if (!saveInProgress) {
      // get post data from storage
      var promises = queue.map(function(){$http.post(<post url>, <post data>).then(function(result){
          // clear successful data
          deferred.resolve(result);
      }, function(error){
         deferred.reject(error);
      })
    })

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

As angular newbie, I am having problems with the above code not being sequential. How can I achieve what I intend to? The queue length is unknown and also the queue length increases as the process is in progress. Please point me to other answers if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Check if you can utilize [angular-queue](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-queue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async.js sounds a good idea but if you don't want to use a library ...

$q.all will batch up an array of requests and fire them at the same time and will resolve when ALL promises in the array resolve - WHICH IS NOT WHAT YOU WANT.

to make $http calls SEQUENTIALLY from an array do this ....

```
var request0 = $http.get('/my/path0');
var request1 = $http.post('/my/path1', {data:'fred'});
var request2 = $http.get('/my/path2');
var requestArray = [];
```

then ...

```
requestArray.push(request0);
requestArray.push(request1);
requestArray.push(request2);
```

then ...

```
requestArray[0].then(function(response0) {
    // do something with response0
    return requestArray[1];
}).then(function(response1) {
    // do something with response1
    return requestArray[2];
}).then(function(response2) {
    // do something with response2
}).catch(function(failedResponse) {
    console.log("i will be displayed when a request fails (if ever)", failedResponse)
});
```

Comment: ok I shall try this. But my request is the same post request with different post data and I don't know how many requests there are to append the "then" to the array.

Comment: i used the 'then' chain to recursively call the process queue responsible for making the http posts if there is still data in local storage. I break from it if the local storage is out of data or post fails. Thanks for the tip about $q.all.

Answer (score 2):

While having a library solution would be great (per @nstoitsev's answer), you can do this without it.

## sequential requests of unknown length

Just to recap:

- we do not know the number of requests
- each response may enqueue another request

A few assumptions:

- all requests will be working on a common data object (local storage in your case)
- all requests are promises

#### running the queue

```
function postMyData (data){
    return $http.post(<url>, data)
}

var rqsts = []

function executeQueue (){

    if(!rqsts.length)
         //we're done
         return

    var rqst = rqsts.shift()        
    rqst()
    .then(function(rsp){
        //based on how you're determining if you need to do another request...  
        if(keepGoing)
            rqsts.push(postMyData(<more data>))           
    })
}
```

**codepen** - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/VaYRXR?editors=1010

I intentionally left this vague because I don't understand what the conditions for failure are and if you wanted to vary up the requests to use more than the same `$http.post` call, you could pass it back in some way.

#### and just a suggestion

> As angular newbie...

Many things are progressing towards this whole *functional, reactive* programming paradigm. Since you're relatively new to Angular and NG2 already has some of this built in, it might be worthy of your attention. I think [rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) is already in many NG2 example bundles.

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar with $q.

Answer (score 1):

The easies way to achieve this is by using [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). There you can find a method called `mapSeries`. You can run it over the queue and it will sequentially process all elements of the array one by one, and will continue to the next element only when the correct callback is called.